# Change page in PhoneGap 1.1.0 with JQm Rc 2

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova

I'm using phoneGap to create smartphone apps, but after I updated my app from jqmobile beta 2, to jqmobile rc 2 my app can't change page.

The code looks like this

```
<a href="javascript:$.mobile.changePage('http://primotours.reklamebureauet-sortkaffe.dk/hotdeals.aspx');" data-role="button" data-theme="f">Afbudsrejser</a>
```

If somebody could help it would very much appreciated, Thanks

Brian

Answer (score 1):

Instead of calling `$.mobile.changePage()`, simply use the url:

```
<a href="http://primotours.reklamebureauet-sortkaffe.dk/hotdeals.aspx" data-role="button" data-theme="f">Afbudsrejser</a>
```

[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/HsLDU/2/)

Comment: I will have to use the Changepage event, if i don't it will just open the browser.

Comment: That depends on your phoneGap-code. Sadly, I am not familiar with phoneGape. But my example above works if you use a simple webView(android)/UIWebView(iOS).

Comment: okay thanks, I will keep that in mind next time. I downgraded to 1.01b of JQmobile, it works for now, sadly the deadline did not give me enough time to find another solution. Thanks for your help!